# RoR JSON.parse catching an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http-status-code-403

Writing an app that reaches out to an api (ETSY) and brings back some JSON but sometimes I get a 403 error and if I get an error I want to show an error page but I'm not sure how to check for that error and do something else.

```
my_hash = JSON.parse(open("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/#{$productId}?api_key=XXXX&fields=title,url,price,description&includes=MainImage").read)
```

I've looked around for a while but haven't seen what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a begin rescue block to redirect the user whenever you hit a 403 error

```
def index
  begin
    my_hash = JSON.parse(open("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/#{$productId}api_key=XXXX&fields=title,url,price,description&includes=MainImage").read)
  rescue
    redirect_to error_path
  end
```

This is sort of quick and dirty, but I beileve it can get the job done.
This article may also help. http://www.mattjohnston.co/blog/2013/10/18/responding-with-errors-in-rails/

Comment: This didn't seem to work, the redirect_to never fires... if it hits an error it just skips this code, thoughts?

Comment: I guess another solution would be to have a check such as so 'if my_hash {success!} else {redirect_to blah} end'. Pretty much check if my_hash is nil, considering it will return a nil value on 403

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your api response, if the response is 404 then render error page. May be something like this. To getting response from api, you need to use third party like (restclient or httpparty).

```
def index
  response = RestClient get "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/#{$productId}api_key=XXXX&fields=title,url,price,description&includes=MainImage"

  unless response.code == 404
   result_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
   // do something 
  else
   // redirect to error page here
  end 
end
```

For reference, pls read restclient documentation [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).